# Defined url function failure

Tags: php

I have a my db connect is included in my header on localhost

when i echo out

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>
```

> Results C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache24/htdocs

when the path should be

> C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/Apache24/htdocs/mycms

if i use the following

```
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mycms/modules/int.php');?>
```

it works but, but is there any way to get the path of the folder its in without adding it hard coded?

I have also tried this

```
<?php include($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '/modules/int.php'));?>
```

Comment: Is the constant defined in the space where you do the include?

Comment: u need file folder path not `http://`, try this `define ('ROOT_URI', 'mycms');`

Comment: did you include that functions file BEFORE you try to using the constant? PHP cannot time travel, and will not retroactively redefine things for you.

Comment: @devpro: including by absolute uri is pretty much never a good idea, but in this case, the include itself never executes, because OP's constant isn't defined.

Comment: Means the include is being called before the constant is being set

Comment: its like server document cannot pick up folder on localhost i have to add it

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` comes directly from the httpd.conf for your site's definition. It's not something that PHP will change on your, or change at runtime. If the path is wrong, then your site is going to be wrong too.

Comment: @MarcB can you look at that last one i posted?

Comment: document_root is literally where your site starts. that's set in apache's config and doesn't change. if you want to access subfolders of your site, then YOU have to provide those subfolders. it's not apache's job to try and figure out the internal code structure of your stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly you want something like this:

```
<?php
    // ASSUMING THE CURRENT FILE IS IN THE DIRECTORY: "mycms"
    defined('SITE_ROOT') or define('SITE_ROOT', __DIR__);
    defined('ROOT_URI')  or define('ROOT_URI', 'http://localhost/mycms');

    include(SITE_ROOT . '/modules/int.php');

    // AND NOT
    include(ROOT_URI . '/modules/int.php');
```